# Building wget with clang/llvm

Tags: optimization, clang

I downloaded the source files for wget and tried to compile it with Clang. I want to configure with the link time optimization (`-flto`). At first, I simply tried:

```
./configure CC=clang CFLAGS=-flto
make
```

The configuration was successful, but I could not run make which output:

> /tmp/lto-llvm-4f0f02.o:ld-temp.o:function _do_handshake: error: undefined reference to 'rpl_fcntl'

and other numerous similar errors, all of the same format (error: undefined reference to xxx).

So I thought I needed to link the files correctly. After searching for answers, I then tried all of the following commands:

```
./configure CC=clang CFLAGS=-flto LDFLAGS=-flto
make
-----------------------------------------------
./configure CC=clang CFLAGS=-flto LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=lld-4.0"
make
-----------------------------------------------
./configure CC=clang CFLAGS=-flto LDFLAGS="-fuse-ld=gold"
make
```

But I am still getting the same error.

I am running this on Debian-9.5. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also specify the specific ar utility to use - the default `ar` and `ranlib` produce `.a` files that are unusable for linking (no entries to use), so for me this worked:

```
./configure CC=clang-4.0 CFLAGS=-flto AR=llvm-ar-4.0 RANLIB=llvm-ranlib-4.0
```

You may get away with just `llvm-ar`, without the version postfix, but you need to ensure that the `clang`, `ar`, and `ranlib` versions match, otherwise you encounter other errors.